# PDFBox 2.0.19:Wrong type of referenced length object COSObject{9, 0}: COSDictionary

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

When I use pdfbox to read the pdf file uploaded by the customer, I encounter the following error：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Wrong type of referenced length object COSObject{9, 0}: COSDictionary
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.getLength(COSParser.java:1078)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseCOSStream(COSParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseFileObject(COSParser.java:925)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:886)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:806)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseDictObjects(COSParser.java:766)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:187)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:226)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1099)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1041)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:989)
```

I open the file with nodepad++, part of which is shown as follows:

```
9 0 obj << 4476 >> endobj
3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [ 7 0 R] /Count 1 >> endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000074 00000 n
0000005126 00000 n
0000000120 00000 n
0000000252 00000 n
0000000362 00000 n
0000000392 00000 n
0000000546 00000 n
0000005042 00000 n
0000005068 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 10
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 4 0 R
>>
startxref
5184
%%EOF
```

I don't know why there is such a file, because it was uploaded by the customer. And this kind of file can be viewed normally.

Is there any other way to read this kind of file correctly?

Comment: Dictionaries consist of key-value pairs e.g <</MyKey 0>>. The purported dictionary at object 9 is thus malformed. Most PDF readers would print a warning and read this as the empty dictionary. Perhaps PDFBox is doing this, and then finding it expects object 9 not to be a dictionary at all! My guess is it is supposed to be just a plain number.  Please show us where object 9 is referenced using "9 0 R"...

Comment: *"And this kind of file can be viewed normally."* - This unfortunately doesn't mean anything. PDF viewers tend to repair very many errors in PDFs under the hood. That is *acceptable* (albeit *not good*) as usually the person viewing the repaired PDF immediately can see whether or not the repair resulted in something usable or in garbage. PDF libraries used for automatic PDF processing, on the other hand, should not repair so much because there often is no such person recognizing the error before the PDF is sent to thousands of people or stored in some legally required archive or ....

Comment: 8 0 obj << /Length 9 0 R >>
stream... endstream
endobj
9 0 obj << 4476 >> endobj

Comment: Yeah, so as other posters guessed, object 9 should just be a plain number. Remove the angle brackets around 4476 and any similar /Lengths, and then run the file through qpdf or cpdf or pdftk to mend the xref tables. Then PDFBox should read it.

Answer (score 1):

Object 9 is incorrect, it should have been:

```
9 0 obj 4476 endobj
```

The library looks for an indirect reference to an integer object while the object contains an invalid dictionary.

Other PDF processors might be more forgiving with such errors and repair the file during load. When it comes to PDF errors, each PDF procesor handles them in its own way.